# avoiding code duplication in Python code

Tags: python, code-duplication, control-flow

Consider the following Python snippet:

```
af=open("a",'r')
bf=open("b", 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(af):
    if i < K:
        bf.write(line)
```

Now, suppose I want to handle the case where `K` is `None`, 
so the writing continues to the end of the file.
I'm currently doing

```
if K is None:
    for i, line in enumerate(af):
        bf.write(line)
else:
    for i, line in enumerate(af):            
        bf.write(line)
        if i==K:
            break
```

This clearly isn't the best way to handle this, as I'm duplicating the code.
Is there some more integrated way I can handle this? The natural thing would be
to have the `if/break` code only be present if `K` is not `None`,
but this involves writing syntax on the fly a la Lisp macros,
which Python can't really do. Just to be clear, I'm not concerned about the particular
case (which I choose partly for its simplicity), so much as learning about general
techniques I may not be familar with.

UPDATE: After reading answers people have posted, and doing more experimentation, here are some more comments.

As said above, I was looking for general techniques that would be generalizable, and I think @Paul's answer,namely using `takewhile` from `iterrools`, fits that best. As a bonus, it is also much faster than the naive method i listed above; I'm not sure why. I'm not really familar with `itertools`, though I've looked at it a few times. From my perspective this is a case of functional programming *For The Win*! (Amusingly, the author of `itertools` once asked for feedback about dropping `takewhile`. See the thread beginning http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-December/522529.html.) I'd simplified my situation above, the actual situation is a bit more messy - I'm writing to two different files in the loop. So the code looks more like:

```
for i, line in enumerate(af):
    if i < K:
        bf.write(line)
        cf.write(line.split(',')[0].strip('"')+'\n')
```

Given my posted example, @Jeff reasonably suggested that in the case when `K` was `None`, I just copy the file. Since in practice I am looping anyway, doing so is not such a clear choice. However, `takewhile` generalizes painlessly to this case. I also had another use case I did not mention here, and was able to use `takewhile` there too, which was nice. The second example looks like (verbatim)

```
i=0
for line in takewhile(illuminacond, af):
    line_split=line.split(',')
    pid=line_split[1][0:3]
    out = line_split[1] + ',' + line_split[2] + ',' + line_split[3][1] + line_split[3][3] + ',' \
                        + line_split[15] + ',' + line_split[9] + ',' + line_split[10]
    if pid!='cnv' and pid!='hCV' and pid!='cnv':
        i = i+1
        of.write(out.strip('"')+'\n')
        tf.write(line)
```

here I was able to use the condition

```
if K is None:
    illuminacond = lambda x: x.split(',')[0] != '[Controls]'
else:
    illuminacond = lambda x: x.split(',')[0] != '[Controls]' and i < K
```

per @Paul's original example. However, I'm not completely happy about the fact that I'm getting `i` from the outer scope, though the code works. Is there a better way of doing this? Or maybe it should be a separate question. Anyway, thanks to everyone who answered my question. Honorable mention to @Jeff, who made some nice suggestions.

Comment: Just a minor remark: For comparisons with None `is` is [prefered](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) over using `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.takewhile` will apply your condition, and then break out of the loop the first time the condition fails.

```
from itertools import takewhile

if K is None:
    condition = lambda x: True
else:
    condition = lambda x: x[0] < K

for i,line in takewhile(condition, enumerate(af)):
    bf.write(line)
```

If K is None, then you don't want takewhile to ever stop, so the condition function should always return True.  But if you are given a numeric value for K, then once the 0'th element of the tuple passed to the condition >= K, then takewhile will stop.

Comment: `takewhile` looks like a nice way to do this. Ironically, the author of `itertools` was considering removing it, see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-December/522529.html. Also, one of the use cases mentioned in that thread namely http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-December/1101471.html was not dissimilar to that under discussion here.

Answer (score 5):

```
for i, line in enumerate(af):  
    if K is None or i < K:
        bf.write(line)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this involves checking two conditions for K at runtime. It doesn't scale. Suppose instead of two cases, I had more?

Comment: It scales just fine. You still loop len(af) times, and comparison to None is very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

If you must loop, how about this?

```
from sys import maxint

limit = K or maxint
for i, line in enumerate(af):
    if i >= limit: break
    bf.write(line)
```

Or even this?

```
from itertools import islice
from sys import maxint

bf.writelines(islice(af, K or maxint))
```

---

Why loop at all in the case that `K` is `None`?

```
from shutil import copyfile


aname = 'a'
bname = 'b'
if K is None:
    copyfile(aname, bname)
else:
    af = open(aname, 'r')
    bf = open(bname, 'w')
    for i, line in enumerate(af):
        if i < K:
            bf.write(line)
```

Comment: Well, the former use of `readline` would just write one line, wouldn't it? Do you mean `read`? That would dump the entire file into memory.

Comment: @Faheem: Oops, I misread your question and thought only the first line should be written in that case.  The second alternative could simplify this.

Comment: @Faheem: In the case of `K` is `None`, it will be easier to just copy the files in that case instead of copying it line by line in code.

Comment: @Jeff: In my actual example, af is not at the beginning of the file when it enters the loop (some lines have already been read), so a straight copy wouldn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jeff: No need to cancel it. It's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @Faheem: I left it in (struck out) since it doesn't work for your particular case.  If I wanted to "cancel" it, I'd remove it completely.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever K is, it's always going to be less than infinity.

```
if K is None:
    K = float('inf') # infinity

for i, line in enumerate(af):            
    bf.write(line)
    if i==K:
        break
```

Or, setting `K = -1` works just as well, though it's less semantically correct.  Ideally you would set K = max lines in af, but I presume that data is not cheaply available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in a situation where you are going to have to accept a trade off between DRY principles and optimizations.

I would start by staying true to DRY principles and remove the duplicate code with a function like `write_until`...

```
def write_until(file_in,file_out,break_on)
    for i,line in enumerate(file_in)

        if break_on(i,line):
            break
        else:
            file_out.write(line)

af=open("a",'r')
bf=open("b", 'w')

if K is None:
    write_until(af,bf,lambda i,line: False)
else:
    write_until(af,bf,lambda i,line: i>K)
```

Then actually use the code and see if you *really* need to do optimizations. How much performance improvement will you honestly see from removing an `if False` check? If you really need that extra speed boost (which I doubt) then you'll just have to live with some code duplication.